# How to fetch contents from different worksheets using a single button in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am newbie in VBA excel . I want to create a button in one worksheet and process to print all the worksheet table row values to a file . I have 3 sheets named "sheet1","sheet2","sheet3" . Button is inside sheet1 . Now i have written some of the code to process that button .

```
Sub Button_Click()
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim Fileout As Object
Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile("myPath\MyFile.txt", True, True)

Set ws = Sheets("sheet2")
Set sh = Sheets("sheet3")

/* I want to print sheet2 table row values to file */

Fileout.Write "print each row to file"

/* I want to get sheet3 table row values to file */

Fileout.Write "print each row to file"

Fileout.Close

End Sub
```

I want to know how to traverse though sheets table rows one by one . Any help ? or Ay suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `for...each` loop like below.

```
dim sh as worksheet, r as row
for each sh in thisworkbook.worksheets
    if sh.name = sh.name = "sheet2" or sh.name = "sheet3" then
        for each r in sh.cells.usedrange.rows
            fileout.write r.value
        next r
    end if
next sh
```